# Spree error when using decorator with the original code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Need a little help over here :-)

I'm trying to extend the Order class using a decorator, but I get an error back, even when I use the exactly same code from source.  For example:

**order_decorator.rb** (the method is exactly like the source, I'm just using a decorator)

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do

def update_from_params(params, permitted_params, request_env = {})
  success = false
  @updating_params = params
  run_callbacks :updating_from_params do
    attributes = @updating_params[:order] ? @updating_params[:order].permit(permitted_params).delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? } : {}

    # Set existing card after setting permitted parameters because
    # rails would slice parameters containg ruby objects, apparently
    existing_card_id = @updating_params[:order] ? @updating_params[:order][:existing_card] : nil

    if existing_card_id.present?
      credit_card = CreditCard.find existing_card_id
      if credit_card.user_id != self.user_id || credit_card.user_id.blank?
        raise Core::GatewayError.new Spree.t(:invalid_credit_card)
      end

      credit_card.verification_value = params[:cvc_confirm] if params[:cvc_confirm].present?

      attributes[:payments_attributes].first[:source] = credit_card
      attributes[:payments_attributes].first[:payment_method_id] = credit_card.payment_method_id
      attributes[:payments_attributes].first.delete :source_attributes
    end

    if attributes[:payments_attributes]
      attributes[:payments_attributes].first[:request_env] = request_env
    end

    success = self.update_attributes(attributes)
    set_shipments_cost if self.shipments.any?
  end

  @updating_params = nil
  success
end

end
```

When I run this code, spree never finds **@updating_params[:order][:existing_card]**, even when I select an existing card. Because of that, I can never complete the transaction using a pre-existent card and bogus gateway(gives me empty blanks errors instead).

I tried to bind the method in **order_decorator.rb** using pry and noticed that the **[:existing_card]** is actuality at **@updating_params**' level and not at **@updating_params[:order]**'s level.

When I delete the decorator, the original code just works fine.

Could somebody explain to me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to redefine is not really the method of the Order class. It is the method that are mixed by Checkout module within the Order class. 
You can see it here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order/checkout.rb

Try to do what you want this way:

Create file `app/models/spree/order/checkout.rb` with code

```
Spree::Order::Checkout.class_eval do
  def self.included(klass)
    super
    klass.class_eval do
      def update_from_params(params, permitted_params, request_env = {})
        ...
        ...
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```